# How to create a transparent topBar and draw behind it (RNN V2)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-native-navigation

I would like to create a Screen with a transparent topBar and want to be able to draw behind it. (React Native Navigation v2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use use a transparent modal which is enabled on your view. This approach however needs a little bit coding... A an alternative, I did something similar by customizing [THIS](https://github.com/mastermoo/react-native-action-button) component. Let me know if it worked for you :)

Comment: Isn't there a build in way in RNN v2?
Having a transparent header as colour, and the ability to draw behind it seems quite basic. (maybe I am wrong)

Comment: There should be! but the point is you should then find a way to overlay your views one on the other. There are some ways  like using "zIndex" but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
class PushedScreen extends Component {
  static options(props) {
    return {
      topBar: {
        title: 'Transparent TopBar',
        background: {
          color: 'transparent',
          translucent: true, // iOS only, optional
          blur: true // iOS only, optional
        }
      },
    };
  }

...
}
```